# How to do stemming in text mining Slovene texts in R

Tags: r, text-mining, stemming

I am text-mining a series of interviews I performed in the Slovene language. After I transformed the vector file into a corpus, I tried this command to stem the words:

```
pupils<- tm_map(pupils, stemDocument(pupils, language = "slovene"))
```

However, the response was this:

> Error in UseMethod("stemDocument", x) :
> no applicable method for 'stemDocument' applied to an object of class "c('VCorpus', 'Corpus')"

I could perform the intended text mining operations (ngrams) without the stemming process, but they will not be completely legit. I saw the post where a gentleman asked about stemming in Italian and was instructed to use the SnowballC package. Unfortunately, SnowballC does not incorporate Slovene, so there's that.

I will appreciate any help. Thank you.
Janez

Comment: Have you tried just using a character vector instead of the corpus? It is the corpus object that is getting rejected.

Comment: I have, both <stemDocument> as well as <wordStem>. Does not work. How about stemming in python and then integrating with R?

Comment: What is "pupils"?  Is it a corpus? A corpus will have the text as well as metadata. From the help text stemDocument() is looking for a character vector or a text document. The error message is telling you that it won't take a corpus which is why I am guess "pupils" is a corpus not a charater vector. You need to feed it just the text, not the full corpus, I believe.

Comment: Your `tm_map` statement is incorrect. It should be: `tm_map(crude, stemDocument, language = "slovene")`.

Comment: Phiver, thank you, it works now! Stomper, pupils is a corpus, but I tried it with a vector, too, but it did not work. However, <tm_map(pupils, stemDocument, language = "slovene")>, does the job, however poorly. Thank you a bunch!